# Partial Derivatives Exercise

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

[Partial Derivatives Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uegVY.png)

Hi, I'm having a bit of trouble solving this partial derivatives question. It's asking me to find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ for
$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2},  & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
0, & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$
and to show that they are both equal to $0$ at $(0,0)$, as well as showing that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}=1$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}=-1$ for the same coordinates.

I'm able to find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =\frac{x^4y-y^5+4x^2y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =\frac{x^5-xy^4-4x^3y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$, but am not sure how to show that they are equal to $0$, as it seems to me they are undefined at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. I don't see any way to cancel out the fraction, so possibly the solution lies in using limits as the function appears to be continuous? But I am not sure why.

Similarly, for Part C, I can find $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} =\frac{x^6+9x^4y^2-9x^2y^4-y^6}{(x^2+y^2)^3}$ but face a similar problem in not simply being able to substitute in the coordinates $(0,0)$ to find $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = 1$, and the same for the other partial.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hint: the definition of partial derivative is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x,0) - f(0,0)}{x}$, and similarly for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. Can you compute these limits? (If you plug in everything, they are very easy)

Comment: @Nick Oh yes! It slipped my mind to utilise the proper definition of partial derivatives, thank you!